# How to set date field in join query ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, join, activerecord

I have below query in which I want to check the date.

The actual working query is like:

```
Quiz.joins(lesson_plan: [private_class: [private_school: 
:joined_private_schools]]).where(joined_private_schools: {user_id: 73}, 
lesson_plans: {is_publish: true})
```

But when I try to set date field it says:

query:

```
Quiz.joins(lesson_plan: [private_class: [private_school: 
:joined_private_schools]]).where(joined_private_schools: {user_id: 73}, 
lesson_plans: {"is_publish = ?, available_due_date_time > ?", true, 
Time.zone.now})
```

Error:

```
SyntaxError: (irb):82: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting =>
 available_due_date_time > ?", true, Time.zone.now})
                              ^
(irb):82: Can't assign to true
able_due_date_time > ?", true, Time.zone.now})
                              ^
(irb):82: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting &. or :: or '[' or '.'
ime > ?", true, Time.zone.now})
                              ^
```

**Update:**

I tried:

query:

```
Quiz.joins(lesson_plan: [private_class: [private_school: 
:joined_private_schools]]).where(joined_private_schools: {user_id: 73}, 
lesson_plans: {"is_publish = ? AND available_due_date_time > ?", true, 
Time.zone.now})
```

But still the error is same.

How to set date in these type of query? Any source for learning are also recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an array to the `.where` clause as mentioned in the [ActiveRecord documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where-label-array).

> If an array is passed, then the first element of the array is treated
>   as a template, and the remaining elements are inserted into the
>   template to generate the condition.

Plus, you can use the table name in the joined query.

> If the relation is the result of a join, you may create a condition
>   which uses any of the tables in the join. For string and array
>   conditions, use the table name in the condition.

The solution:

```
Quiz.joins(lesson_plan: [private_class: [private_school: :joined_private_schools]])
    .where(joined_private_schools: { user_id: 73 })
    .where(["lesson_plans.is_publish = ? AND lesson_plans.available_due_date_time > ?", true, Time.zone.now])
```

Comment: What is the meaning of `treated as a template`?

Comment: The template is the part with the question marks. Notice that we don't provide there our values at first, but we just specify that they will be in that specific place. Our values are provided as the second and the third elements of the array.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explanation. makes sense :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.where(joined_private_schools: {user_id: 73}).where('lesson_plans.is_publish = ? AND lesson_plans.available_due_date_time > ?', true, Time.zone.now)
```

**Edit**

Also, check the [Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html). You can find there a lot of information to perform most of the queries you'll need.